# Creating a Filemaker layout to add 0 to n records to a record in another table.

Tags: database-design, layout, many-to-many, filemaker

I have 3 tables (for clarity am only listing some fields):

**Table 1** (*ID*, *Description1*)

**Table 2** (*ID*, *Description2*)

**Table 3** (*ID*, *Table1ID*, *Table2ID*)

Essentially I am using **Table 3** to create a many-to-many join (and have linked the various IDs through the relationships tab and set the ID fields to be autocreated).  I want to be able to create a layout with all records from **Table 1** and allow a user to select 0 to n items from **Table 2** in a dropdown.

So far I have a layout that contains the **Table 1** *Description 1* field and have tried putting a portal with the *Description 2* field from **Table 2**.  I then changed the control style to dropdown through the inspector and **Table 2** in the Values from: property.

I am not sure if this is even possible or the correct approach.  I was hoping Filemaker would use the relationship graph and create the necessary records (essentially entries in **Table 3** linking the two together), but I receive the following error: "***This operation cannot be performed because one or more required related records are not available and cannot be created.***"

Any help would be appreciated and please go easy on the Filemaker newbie :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to create your value list (and that is not a part of the relationship graph). You do this at File > Manage > Value Lists.

You can create a new value list and tell it to **Use values from field** (first radio option, not selected in image):

[image: Use values from field]

Once in the **Use values from field** dialogue, you can select to also display values from a second field (the id is the first, the description is 2nd), include all values, and only show values from the first field (to hide the id from the user).

[image]

You are correct that your relationship graph will do the work of creating related records and filling in the keys for you. It should look like this:

[image: Relationship graph]

It is important that the '**Allow creation of records in this table via this relationship**' is checked in your relationship, exactly as follows:

[image: Allow creation of records in this table via this relationship is checked]

Your layout, as you said, is based on table one and your portal looks at table three. The '**Show vertical scrollbar**' will allow you to create an unlimited number of related records. Without that option selected, you are limited to the number of rows in the portal.

[image]

That is it. Save your layout, create a record in table one, and you can create related records through your relationship graph with no scripting needed.

You are storing the id and displaying the description.

[image: Success!]

Comment: Brilliant Ted, was beginning to despair.  This works just as I want it to.  I had ticked the Allow Creations of Records in this Table... for Table 1 not Table 3, fixed that and all works a treat.  Just one slight issue that my vertical scroll bar is not showing on the portal even though the box was checked on creation.  I'll look into that one.  Cheers again, Dave.

Comment: Wait, I think I might have misunderstood and the code I gave you will not do what you want. I will try to update this later today but have to get on a subway now.

Comment: I am confused now.  Your original answer (before the edits) did what I wanted it too and I can't see what was wrong with it and why this approach is better.  Told you I was a newbie :o)

Comment: The original answer only looked like it was working on the surface. Create a few records and then look at all 3 tables in table view. You should see what is wrong with the original answer (data in wrong table and field).

Answer (score 0):

It's almost correct; you need to have a portal to Table 3, allow to create records via this relationship, place the Table3::Table2ID there, and format it as a pop-up menu. The value list for the menu must be based on Table2 and include Table2::ID and Table2::Description2; you'll probably want to only show the second column.

When you select an item from the menu, FileMaker will add a new record in Table3 with the required IDs (or change the existing record, if you're modifying a row).

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, will give it a whirl and let you know how I get on.  Dave

Comment: This is exactly right. I was mistaken earlier. My updated answer is the strategy you suggest with screenshots. I apologize for misunderstanding your answer earlier. If you edit your answer I can upvote it.